# Есть ли механизм подтверждения выполнения действий на Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте.
После изменения данных в БД необходимо оповестить пользователя об этом (Ваши данные успешно изменены или не изменены-проверьте ошибки, в случае чего).
Есть ли в Yii2 какой-нибудь удобный механизм для выдачи таких сообщений/окон? 
Нагуглить не получается.

Comment: http://atoumus.github.io/yii2-flash-messages.html

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Кто эти данные изменяет? Если сам пользователь, то после сохранения добавьте:

```
\Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Ваши данные успешно изменены или не изменены-проверьте ошибки, в случае чего');
```

Будет выдан бутстраповский алерт.

Comment: От данного способа отказаться пришлось, потому что в случае "в случае чего" - я диплом не защищу))) Ну,, при успешной валидации формы все окей, а вот если есть ошибки, то обработать в контроллере это не выходит, ибо пост еще не пришел (из-за клиентской валидации), а как отловить это, кроме как else'ом не дошло. И в итоге оно постоянно высвечивалось. Такие дела. Переделала верстку с пошаговой регистрации на одну страницу, обойдутся без наворотов.